# How many VM instances are in an Azure pricing plan

Tags: azure, azure-app-service-plans

In [App Service plan overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-hosting-plans) it is written:

> In the dedicated compute tiers (Basic, Standard, Premium, PremiumV2,
> PremiumV3), the App Service plan defines the number of VM instances
> the apps are scaled to, so each VM instance in the App Service plan is
> charged. These VM instances are charged the same regardless how many
> apps are running on them.

Where is the information how many VM instances does each App Service plan use?

The prices in [App Service pricing](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/app-service/windows/) are for all VM instances of the plan together or the price is per VM instance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pricing is per instance. When you create a new plan, you select the VM size and you get one instance. When you scale a Web App to 3 instances, you will pay for 3 instances.